# .slideDown() after certain height only once, listening to .scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got this problem where I got an section (".aboutsection") that's hidden at first, needs to be revealed when hitting a certain point on the webpage and then start to animate the .slideDown(). I got it working, but everytime I scroll past that certain point it starts the animation over and over again and that's not what I want.

I sought for different solutions, but neither of them work nor match my needs.
*(So please don't put this as a copy)*

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

 var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
 $(".aboutcontainer").hide();

 [...] (left out other function listening to scrolltop)

 if(wScroll > $('section.about').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {

  $(".aboutcontainer").slideDown(1400,'easeInOutQuart');

 }

});
```

I've tried to let the function check if ".aboutcontainer" is ":visible" or ":hidden" to only animate it when the section is hidden, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just set a flag and check as part of your conditional:

```
var expanded = false;
$(".aboutcontainer").hide();
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  [...] (left out other function listening to scrolltop)

  if(!expanded && wScroll > $('section.about').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
    expanded = true;

   $(".aboutcontainer").slideDown(1400,'easeInOutQuart');

  }

});
```

Comment: Well, it works... sort of. Now after I scroll when the .scrolldown() is only done once, it stays display: none. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough: 

I need to get the .slideDown() only once and then I need to keep the section displayed. Tried a callback function, but didn't seem to work the way I did it.

Comment: You are hiding the content every time someone scrolls with this line: `$(".aboutcontainer").hide();`.  You should move that outside of your `$(window).scroll` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since `slideDown` manipulates the height of the object have you tried to check if the height is greater than 0?

```
if(wScroll > $('section.about').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
    if( $(".aboutcontainer").height() < 0 ){
        $(".aboutcontainer").slideDown(1400,'easeInOutQuart');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I see where this is going, but I think I spotted a mistake: Now the .slideDown() will animate when the height is **bigger** than 0, so for that matter it's just the same. However, I tried "<" and "<=", but now it doesn't animate at all.